# command for generating parser with bison/flex in windows?

Tags: compiler-construction, bison

I am trying design a compiler for my grammar. I write the scanner code and it works correctly with flex.
Now I write parser code , symbol table , and three.h for generating 3-address code.
But I don't know how to run & test some file with it using Bison. How do I invoke bison on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need bison on windows, which are provided by Cygwin, MinGW or GnuWin. These projects provides bison in a way that it can be used on windows like it is used on unix.

```
...My\source\dir> path\to\bison.exe -o foo.c foo.y
```